# How to properly handle the response from mergeMap?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I need to send a series of actions consecutively, these actions will be processed by the same effect. This effect sends a series of calls to a service with a small parameter change. `mergeMap` allows me to make this series of calls but I have a problem when trying to process the results because I only get one response. I need the answer of every call

component class

```
onFilter($event: FilterModel): void {
  const [startDate, endDate] = $event.dateRange;
  const organization = $event.organization;

  this.store.dispatch(
    filter({ path: 'access', startDate, endDate })
  );
  this.store.dispatch(
    filter({ path: 'points', startDate, endDate })
  );
  this.store.dispatch(
    filter({ path: 'content', startDate, endDate })
  );
  this.store.dispatch(
    filter({ path: 'steps', startDate, endDate })
  );
}
```

action

```
export const filter = createAction(
  '[Some component] Apply filter',
  props<{
    path: PathType;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
  }>()
);
```

effect

```
filter$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(filter),
    mergeMap((action) =>
      this.someService
        .filter(
          action.path,
          action.startDate,
          action.endDate,
        )
        .pipe(
          map((response) => {
            this.messageService.add({
              severity: 'success',
              summary: this.translateService.instant('shared.success'),
            });

            if (action.path === 'access') {
              return handleLogins({ payload: response });
            }

            if (action.path === 'user_point') {
              return handlePoints({ payload: response });
            }

            if (action.path === 'content') {
              return handleContent({ payload: response });
            }

            return handleSteps({ payload: response });
          }),
          catchError(() => {
            this.messageService.add({
              severity: 'error',
              summary: this.translateService.instant('shared.fail'),
            });

            return EMPTY;
          })
        )
    )
  )
);
```

I can verify in redux toolbar that all actions are processed but when trying to process the response I only get data from the response of the first call

[image]

If you identify that I can handle the scenario in a better way, I appreciate the advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yztub?file=src/app/counter.effects.ts.  I create a simple sample. check this console. I think your problem maybe is api or httpclient block your request? because your effect didn't use switchMap or exhaustmap. and also I think your catcherror need to return a error action or failure action. maybe easy to track bug.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? maybe your second request is failed (bad request or internal server error or whatever), which causes the effect to be stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Check your network tab to verify all requests are returning something, and also check if there are no exceptions somewhere. `mergeMap` doesn't cancel any emits, so all actions should be handled.

Dispatching multiple actions sequentially is a bad practice though, for more info see the NgRx ESLint plugin rule - https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/avoid-dispatching-multiple-actions-sequentially.md.

Instead, dispatch 1 action and have 4 different actions to send the requests.
This will also make it easier to debug if a request is causing issues.